# Find orthogonal vectors from given vectors. v3 and v4 from v1 and v2

Tags: vectors

Vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are given below

$v_1 =\begin{bmatrix}  −1  &   2 &   3  &   0  \end{bmatrix}$

$v_2=\begin{bmatrix}  −1   &   1  &  −1   &  0  \end{bmatrix}$

(a) Find a non-zero vector $v_3$ which is orthogonal to both $v_1$ and $v_2$.
(b) Find a non-zero vector $v_4$ which is orthogonal to $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$.

Comment: I know it can be solved by using gram Schmidt process but I dont know from where to start?

Comment: Do you understand how the process works? You start with 'making' $v_3$ from $v_1$ and $v_2$. You could also, simply by inspection, suggest $v_3=(0,0,0,1)$ and then find $v_4$.

Comment: how to find v3 ..I am completely stuck..

Comment: Do you know how to find the null space of a matrix?

Comment: yes  I know how to find null space

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ the vector orthogonal to the two given vectors can be obtained with cross-product:
$$\vec{u}=\vec{v}\times\vec{w}=\left|\begin{array}c v_1&v_2&v_3 \\w_1&w_2&w_3 \\ \vec{i} & \vec{j} & \vec{k}  \end{array} \right|$$
where $\vec{i}=(1,0,0)$, $\vec{j}=(0,1,0)$, $\vec{k}=(0,0,1)$

**Hint 2**

What is the dot product of $\vec{v}=(v_1,v_2,v_3,0)$ and $\vec{x}=(0,0,0,x_4)$?

Comment: the dot product will be zero but I still dont know how to find v3 from these two vectors

Comment: @alma what does that mean, if the dot product os zero?
Also there is bijection  $f:\mathbb{R}^3\times\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^3$, $f((x_1,x_2,x_3,0))=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, so vectors $\vec{v_1}$ and $\vec{v_2}$ in this case can be reprezented by vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, from which you can by using Hint1 create another 3D vector.